# Error when I make a connection through sequel - mysql2 on AmazonWs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, bundle, mysql2, engineyard

My rb file is simple like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'
require 'sequel'

Sequel.connect(:adapter => 'mysql2', :database=>'xxx', :user => 'xxx', :password => 'xxxxxx', :host => 'xxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com')
```

when I ran this file I got the following error:

```
> /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
  `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)    from
> /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
  `require'     from t.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I ran the command "bundle list" over my amazon instance and I got the following list:

Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.8)
  * actionpack (3.2.8)
  * activemodel (3.2.8)
  * activerecord (3.2.8)
  * activeresource (3.2.8)
  * activesupport (3.2.8)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.0.21)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.1.1)
  * json (1.7.5)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.19)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * mysql2 (0.3.11)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.8)
  * railties (3.2.8)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * sass (3.2.1)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sequel (3.38.0)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * thor (0.16.0)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)

So as we can see there is the mysql2 gem. Any advise?

Thanks all!

Comment: As you can see from the backtrace, the error is raised by the require 'mysql2' statement on the second line, before you even require Sequel, so the problem is not with Sequel.  My guess is something in your environment.  "bundle list" may show mysql2, but are you running your code with "bundle exec"?  What does "gem list mysql2" show?

Comment: Yes I executed with bundle exec before and I didn't succeed, I even tried ruby file.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Solve it. In my local environment I edited by hand the Gemfile (maybe is not the right way) I added one line "gem mysql2" then in the console I execute "bundle install" and upload the Gemfile to github.

Finally, in the amazon instance I deployed my environment to apply changes and execute the command "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec file.rb" (always use production) and the file execute normal.

Thanks all!